# Put values over my bars, barplot (Data labels)

Tags: r, text, bar-chart

I would like to put the values over my bars, this is the code I have for my barplot:

```
grafico=barplot(as.matrix(w),las=2,beside=T, horiz=F,ces.names=1.5,col=c("lightblue","lightgrey","darkgrey"),cex.axis=1, cex.names=0.78, main = "Figura 2. Escuelas",xpd=T)
legend(1,0.8, rownames(w), col=c("lightblue","lightgrey","darkgrey"),cex = 0.59,lwd=5)
```

This is the chart I have. Need values where the red arrows I tried to draw are :). Thanks everyone
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5OBi.png)

Comment: Use the `?text` function with x=grafico and y=w

Comment: Thanks good Sir. I tried this and works!   text(grafico,w-0.02,w)